# Allow Invalid Keyword Argument on Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Anyone know how to prevent Django from raising a TypeError on save when a field isn't present? I've included simplified models below. Essentially, I'd like to pass a 'name' attribute when creating a Tag. A custom save action would then get_or_create a TagDetail with the name and create the association.

```
class TagDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    detail = models.ForeignKey(TagDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Show views.py and template

Comment: Can you just show what your codes are, exactly where you think the issue has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `blank=True` for the field. If you need it required later you can set that on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have some fields in your Tag model that are required and can't remain empty, `content_type` and `object_id`

> **YOU:** You'd like to pass a 'name' attribute when creating a Tag. A custom save action would then get_or_create a TagDetail with the name and create the association

The process is you call save() for the Model, then you call `get_or_create` method to create the TagDetails with the name... No issue so far

But when you save the Tag, even with the association `detail= tag_details_instance`, actually you let these fields `content_type` and `object_id` empty. You did not tell the db to set blank or null to these fields

**Solution #1**
If you have data for these fields, when you create the Tag, make sure to assign them with values.

**Solution #2**
Edit your Tag Model with:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    detail = models.ForeignKey(TagDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

If you care so much about to keep the same behavior as on_delete=models.CASCADE in `content_type` field, you can add a signal `pre/post_delete`